# Ajax form submit returns error on first submit but submits on second click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to use ajax form submit to submit a form without refreshing the page. However when I click the submit button for the first time, it alerts the error (in alert it shows the whole html page where I have the submit form). And if I close the alert and hit the same submit button again without refreshing the page, it submits the form perfectly.

So, every time I refresh the page I have to hit the submit button and then close the error alert and then submit it again. I am pretty sure its some syntax error in the ajax file.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  /* validation */
  $("#login-form").validate({
    rules: {
      upass: {
        required: true
      },
      uemail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      upass: {
        required: "please enter your password"
      },
      uemail: "please enter your email address",
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    submitHandler: submitForm
  });
  /* validation */

  /* login submit */
  function submitForm() {
    var data = $("#login-form").serialize();

    $.ajax({

      type: 'POST',
      url: 'login.php',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        // console.log(data);
        // alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        // if(response == 1){
        if (data.status == 'success') {
          // alert('Good!');
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          window.location.href = "home.php";
        } else {
          window.location.href = "login_failed.php";
        }
      },
      error: function(data) {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

});
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/signup-form.css" type="text/css" />

  </head>
  <body>
  <!--container starts-->
  <div class="container">


      <!--Header starts-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
              <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" style="float:left"/></a>
        </div>


        <form method="post" action="login.php" id="login-form" class="form-inline" autocomplete="off">

        <div class="form-group"><strong style="color:white; font-family:tahoma">Email:</strong>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="uemail" id="user_email" />

        </div>



          <!--<input type="email" name="uemail" placeholder="Email" required/>-->
          <!--<input type="email" name="u_email" placeholder="Email" required="required"/>-->

        <div class="form-group"><strong style="color:white; font-family:tahoma">Password:</strong>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="upass" />

        </div>


          <!--<input type="password" name="upass" placeholder="Password" required/>-->
          <!--<input type="password" name="u_pass" placeholder="********" required="required"/>-->
          <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-default">Login</button></br>
          <!--<button type="submit" name="login"> Login </button>-->

          <a href="forgot_password.php">Forgot your password?</a>
        </form>
              </div>
            </nav>



  <script src="js_files/login.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="js_files/login_failed.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="register_script.js"></script> -->
  <script src="js_files/sign_up.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And this the php file login.php

```
<?php

require_once 'class/head.class.php';

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $u_email = $_POST['uemail'];
    $u_pass = $_POST['upass'];


    try {

        if(init::loginCheck($u_email) < 3){
            if(users::login($u_email, $u_pass)) {
                init::loginSuccess($u_email);
                // init::redirect('home.php');

                $response['status'] = 'success';
                // $response['message'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> &nbsp; registered sucessfully, please confirm your email</div>';
                // echo 1;
            } else {
                init::loginAttempt($u_email);

                // init::redirect('home.php');

                $response['status'] = 'redirect'; // could not register

                // $response['message'] = '<div class="alert alert-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; You have entered incorrect login details. Please try again</div>';
                // echo 0;
            }
        }
        else {

            $response['status'] = 'redirect';

        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

echo json_encode($response);
}


?>
```

The error it returns is the html page that contains form:

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\n\n  \n\n\n\nhttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js\">\n    \n\n\nhttps://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js\" integrity=\"sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\n\n\n\nhttps://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css\" integrity=\"sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\n\n\nhttps://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css\" integrity=\"sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\n\n\n    \n  \n  \n  \n  \n    \n    \n      \n            \n              \n        \n        \n        \n\n\n        \n          \n        Email:\n        \n        \n        \n\n\n          \n          -->\n          -->\n\n        Password:\n        \n\n        \n\n          \n          -->\n          -->\n          Login\n           Login </button>-->\n\n          Forgot your password?\n        \n              \n            \n\n  \n\n  \n  </script> -->\n  </script> -->\n  \n\n  \n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: got any html we can see?

Comment: what error it returns?

Comment: the code for the form..

Comment: @Rick . I have added the html and php code. Thanks

Comment: @santoshgore . I have added the error it shows. Thanks

Comment: what error it shows in console?

Comment: @santoshgore. I have commented out the console.log now but when I uncomment it, then it shows the same error as in the alert

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on as I'm not finding any issues. I'd check your ajax url `url: 'login.php'` to see if that is correct. Works here fine: https://jsfiddle.net/yepm4fd3/

Answer (score 0):

add this in your ajax request

```
async: false,
```

this will fixed your error and also add this to view any error from ajax request

```
error: function(er, err, error){
  alert(error);
};
```